# Unit testing retrofit2 call giving me a null when mocking Call<Void>

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I've seen a lot of different ways people have tested their unit tests for retrofit2 and I feel like this has been the closest I've come. I'm able to mock my api interface but when it comes down to mocking the call, the call always comes back `null`. Is there anything that I'm missing or doing incorrectly?

Here is my test method:

```
@Test
public void testApiSuccess() {
    TestRequestBody testRequestBody = Util.getTestBody();

    ApiService mockedApiService = Mockito.mock(ApiService.class);
    Call<Void> mockedCall = Mockito.any(Call.class);

    when(mRestClient.apiService()).thenReturn(mockedApiService);
    Mockito.when(mockedApiService.executeApi(testRequest)).thenReturn(mockedCall);

    Mockito.doAnswer(invocation -> {
        Callback<Void> callback = invocation.getArgumentAt(0, Callback.class);
        callback.onResponse(mockedCall, Response.success(null));
        return null;
    }).when(mockedCall).enqueue(any(Callback.class));

    presenter.executeApi();
    verify(view).showSuccess();
}
```

The code block that I'm testing is as follows:

```
@Override
public void executeApi() {
    RequestBody requestBody = getRequestbody();

    Call<Void> call = mRestClient.apiService().executeApi(requestBody);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
            if (response != null && response.code() == 200) {
                view.showSuccess();
            } else {
                view.showError();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
            view.showError();
        }
    });
}
```

My test goes up until the `call.enqueue` and fails here because the `call` is null. Something is wrong when I'm trying to mock the `call`. Been stumped here now for half the day. Any clues could help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because the request body you are expecting to be passed to `executeApi()` in the mock is not the same body that is passed to `executeApi()` in the code block, as in, `getRequestBody();` != `Util.getTestBody();` so your mocked call is never returned.

The solution would be to make the request body a parameter at the presenter level as well; this way from your test, you can call `presenter.executeApi(testRequestBody);` which will call executeApi with the expected parameter and return your mocked `Call`.